# Joomla routing doesn't work for inner pages on PHP7.4

Tags: php7

Whenever I use PHP7.4 I cannot change page, changing back to PHP7.3 works.

Is there a PHP setting I need to activate to get the redirects to work?

I'm getting

** 404 Not Found ** and it's not my 404 page it's the apache one.

There are no PHP error logs for this site (new site).

This is using J2Store on the site, which works on the homepage.  But individual pages for J2Store or the core do not work.  It's a 404 at any point, but downgrading to PHP7.3 works.

Browser console shows no errors other than 404 not found.

Comment: `I cannot change the page`. Is this in Joomla core or a custom component? If core, which core component? Have you checked the PHP logs? Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: Updated question.  Thanks for the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh crap.

It would help if you have `.htaccess` activated.

I could have sworn this happened on two occaisions.